# How do I retrieve my forgotten passpharase on my PPC server?

Tags: boot, server

So recently I installed Ubuntu server on my Power PC mac mini. But, now it takes me through 
Yaboot and asks me to enter my passphrase so it can unlock the disk. I forgot my passphrase. Can I install a different flavor of linux or is there a workaround. Pressing shift during boot doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/

This may help - It allows you to delete your old password, and reset it.